# Python: как заблокировать клавиши для всего, кроме модуля keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, hotkeys

У меня есть программа, которая должна подставлять определённые символы и комбинации символов при нажатии определённых клавиш:

```py
import keyboard

while True:
    hotkey = keyboard.read_hotkey(suppress=False)
    if hotkey == 'j+k':
        keyboard.write('j + k')
```

(Я не использую `keyboard.add_hotkey()`, потому что в дальнейшем в моих планах не конкретные горячие клавиши, а проверка на наличие определённых клавиш в hotkey. Но это не меняет ситуацию: add_hotkey() ведёт себя так же)
Я ожидаю, что при запуске этой программы, когда я буду одновременно нажимать <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, скажем, в текстовом редакторе, будет печататься 'j + k'. Но я получаю 'jkj + k'. То есть сами клавиши <kbd>j</kbd> и <kbd>k</kbd> передаются текстовому редактору до срабатывания функции.
Если я сделаю:

```py
keyboard.block_key('j')
keyboard.block_key('k')
```

, эти клавиши не будут обрабатываться и `read_hotkey`.

Вопрос: возможно ли сделать так, чтобы определённые клавиши были заблокированы для всего, кроме listener-а в keyboard? То есть чтобы в момент работы программы эти клавиши не могли выполнять других функций?

UPD: Я обнаружил, что при заблокированных клавишах всё ещё срабатывает `keyboard.is_pressed()`, и у меня родился вот такой код:

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.block_key('j')
keyboard.block_key('k')

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('j+k'):
        keyboard.write('j + k')
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске такого кода в фоне клавиатура начинает сильно тормозить (видимо из-за огромного количества проверок в цикле). Если кто-то подскажет, как оптимизировать такой код, это тоже будет отличным решением проблемы.

Comment: Какая операционка?

Comment: Windows 11. О кроссплатформенности пока не думаю.

Comment: А просто backspace дважды послать - не вариант?

Comment: Кстати, этот while true процессор не выжирает?

Comment: уточните куда должна происходить вставка в gui (Tk, Qt), другую программу, консоль?

Comment: Daniil Loban, моя цель - любой текстовый редактор или процессор (стандартный блокнот, Notepad++, Word и так далее). То есть в идеале - хочу полностью изменить поведение определённых клавиш при работе программы.

Comment: я думаю тебе надо в сторону WinAPI смотреть. Так как ты должен системе сказать, что теперь все нажатия на клавиатуре проходят через тебя. Больше смахивает на попытку написать драйвер. Иначе событие сгенерировано и отправлено всем листенерам. Или, как уже подсказали, генерировать backspace'ы до применения своих макросов.

Comment: вот тут показывается как делать [Блокирование системных клавиш и их комбинации](https://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread117073.html) возможно будет полезна [программа](https://www.directedge.us/content/winhotkey/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы клавиатура не тормозила нужно использовать следующий код:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        # Проверяем клавиши здесь
    except AttributeError:
        # Выводим сообщение об ошибке, если нужно

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

В данном случае вы всегда ожидаете нажатие клавиши не в основном потоке. Да, я знаю как организованы потоки в python и не буду сильно углубляться в эту тему, а просто дам код решения.

Comment: Но это не блокирует клавиши, кроме того, кажется, срабатывает для отдельных клавиш, но не для их сочетаний (hotkeys). С Pynput, честно говоря, знаком плохо, поэтому пока не представляю, возможна ли там работа с горячими клавишами?

Comment: Клавиши блокирует, насчет сочетаний не скажу точно, но раньше работало.

Comment: @Futyn Уточнил, да, с горячими клавишами работать можно, более гибкую настройку можно делать, документация написана хорошо